# Separate update and render

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm programming a simple Snake in Java. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Java and Game Developing, so please bear with me ;)

Until now, I have been using a UI thread, as well as a update-thread.
The update thread just set the position, set the `GameObject`s, and so on.

I didn't think much of concurrency, but now I've come to a problem.

I wanted to modify the `ArrayList<GameObject>`, but it throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

With a little research I found out that this happens because the two threads are trying to access the variables at the same time.

But I didn't really find a way to prevent this.
I thought about copying the array and swapping them out when the rendering is finished, but I would have to deep-copy them, which isn't really the best solution in my opinion.
It probably eats up more CPU resources than a single-threaded game.

Are there any other ways to prevent this?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why do you use threads?

Comment: @Liosan

1. So the game loop doesn't block the ui thread.
2. For practise.

Comment: Have you tried making your `Collection` [thread safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)? One way to achieve this is using the [synchronizedCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)) method.

Comment: A thread safe Collection isn't going to make a thread safe program. Even with a synchronized collection, you will still be rendering the world in an inconsistent state. Either guard the entire update operation with a mutex, or better yet, don't use multi-threading without proper motivation. If your rendering takes so long as to lock up your UI, you have a bigger problem :) If your game updates take too long, consider splitting the work into smaller pieces and spread them out over several frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use wait and notify to ensure that only one of your threads is modifying the object at a time. You'll need a class to hold your ArrayList:

```
class GameObjectManager {
    private ArrayList<GameObject> objects;
    private Boolean rendering = false;

    public GameObjectManager(){
        //Initialize objects
    }

    public synchronized void update() {
        if (rendering)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }

        // update objects...

        rendering = true;
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized void render() {
        if (!rendering)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
            }

        // render objects...

        rendering = false;
        notify();
    }
}
```

The Update thread might look something like this:

```
class UpdateThread implements Runnable {
    private GameObjectManager manager;

    public UpdateThread(GameObjectManager m) {
        this.manager = m;
        new Thread(this, "Update").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            m.update();
        }
    }
}
```

The Render thread would follow suit:

```
class RenderThread implements Runnable {
    private GameObjectManager manager;

    public RenderThread(GameObjectManager m) {
        this.manager = m;
        new Thread(this, "Render").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            m.render();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the main function that controls it all would do something resembling this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    GameObjectManager manager = new GameObjectManager();
    new UpdateThread(manager);
    new RenderThread(manager);
    System.out.println("The game is running now...");
}
```

So here's what happens:
 1. The main function creates two threads, the update and render threads.
 2. Both threads try to do their task, but the `GameObjectManager` forces the render thread to `wait()` until the update thread has called `notify()`.
 3. The update thread finishes updating, notifies the render thread, and then waits.
 4. The render thread finishes rendering, notifies the update thread, and then waits.

And so on.

Comment: How is this an improvement over just using a single thread?

Comment: Just wanted to ask this, I loose the advantages of multithreading with this...

Comment: Updating and Rendering have to happen in sequence, there are no advantages to multithreading them at all. This is just a way to sequence them if you have threads in place already.

Comment: @NSAddict If this removes all the advantages of multi-threading then you're not threading the right parts of your code. Eric has given you a correct answer that solves your concurrent modification issues. Deciding what code to thread is a different problem.